# BitCoin Miner - Remote Miners with SSH Access only

Tags: miner-configuration

I've graciously been given a big opportunity with a server infrastructure to work with, and I'd like to start it off by starting some Bitcoin mining, however there's a catch. These servers I have access to have all internet access blocked other then the SSH connection that I make in to the machines.

Is there any bit of software that for example, can receive the piece of a block to solve on my main machine at home, and send it off to these servers through SSH to solve, then send it back?

Comment: Calculate your server hashrate, before you proceed with mining.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is tunneling through SSH. Assuming you can connect to an SSH from the servers (outgoing TCP port 22 is allowed). `A` is the machine you want to run the miner on, `B` is the SSH server which we use to tunnel the traffic through (this has to be able to open connections to the mining pool) and `C` is the hostname of the mining pool you want to mine on, then it's a simple matter of doing the following on `A`:

```
ssh -L 8888:C:1234 B
```

and then pointing your mining software to `localhost:8888`. What this does is open a connection to `B` which may open connections to the mining pool and each connection to the local port `8888` will be transparently forwarded to `C`. Notice that you'll also have to change the port from `1234` to whatever your mining pool uses.